# Develop plugins in sylius Best practice?

Tags: sylius

Is there a way to develop plugins in main directory of the project not in vendor.
A way to autoload the plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just declare a new [Sylius Plugin](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/book/plugins/creating-plugin.html). With this guidelines you should be able to start working on your bundle.

Just make sure to declare your custom Vendor in your Sylius roots composer.json:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Mgs\\SyliusThemePlugin\\": "lib/MgsSyliusThemePlugin/src"
    }
},
...
```

Make sure to run `composer dump-autoload` afterwards, so that the Autoloader will catch upon your new code.

Comment: i wouldn't have thought about this Thanks!